# How to exclude group from deleting

Tags: regex

i have this regex:

```
(%)([[:punct:]&[:alnum:]& ]{1,1})(%)
```

https://regex101.com/r/FUmP8G/1

and it's deleting whole 3 groups, how to keep 2nd group for searching but exclude it from deleting?

For example:

%@%

Result:

@

Comment: In the replacement use group 2. Or use `%([[:punct:][:alnum:] ])%` and replace with group 1 https://regex101.com/r/vuVtw9/1

Comment: @The fourth bird Thank you.

Comment: I don't see anything being replaced in your demo link. But you are matching 3 groups which you seem to want to replace with 1 group. How can that be done ?

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern `/(?<=[%])([[:punct:]&[:alnum:]& ]{1,1})(?<![%])/`

here a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/7CfCbf/1)